# How can I set up email functionality like Craigslist?

Tags: php, jquery

I want a button that when pressed brings up a list of possible email providers (similar to the one that can be found on Craigslist). Then a user can choose the email provider that suits their needs and the "To" and "Subject" get automatically populated. I understand that I can set up a link that automatically populates using Outlook, but that isn't what I am looking for. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it.

[Here](http://sfbay.craigslist.org/eby/app/3622750717.html) is a Craigslist ad where the functionality can be viewed. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the function you describe. I clicked on "email to a friend" and it brought up a form, but never asked about providers. If I click on the Reply button, it opens my default mail client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you'd need to program a popup dialog box. I'd recommend using jQuery UI's addon `dialog` for that.  Then you'll need to look at the API docs for each email provider and figure out exactly what parameters you need to pass them in a `$_GET` string to display what you want on their page.  All the custom From, To, Subject, etc is handled by the API, unique to each email provider.

Start here for the Google Dev API: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-migration/v1/auth